# Is there any AC voltage sensor available like as Rogowski coil for current?

Tags: voltage, power, ac, sensor, power-electronics

I am making a device to measure AC voltage. I want to measure voltage just by clamping the probes around the wire (like we do with Rogowski coil to measure current). However, I am only able to find sensors like ZMPT101B which needs to be directly connected at the sensing point. Is there any as such AC voltage sensor available?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Looks like it can be done, at least after some calibration: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7151301

Comment: @DamienD Yes, it is possible, as shown in the video https://youtu.be/2T5gvAgl_SQ but that's the whole complete product. I am in search of a sensor that they must be using then I will connect it with my Arduino or pi!

Comment: Note: This should not be construed as a question looking for specific parts (that would be off-topic) but rather a question asking whether this can be done in general, and how.

Answer (score 0):

Any conductor placed close to a wire will have some capacitive coupling to it. It's then 'merely' a case of calibrating the division ratio between that and the capacitive loading on your conductor. Unfortunately, everything will have some capacitive coupling to everything, and maintaining the calibration will be very difficult. You can reduce this effect with the judicious placement of earthed shields. However, you'll end up with a custom assembly for each AC conductor you want to monitor, rather than something you can buy off the shelf, or build repeatably.

I might be mistaken, but I think I heard a long time ago that certain types of optical fibre rotated the plane of polarised light according to the voltage gradient they passed through. They were being touted as non-contact voltage measurement for power lines. I've not heard of them ever again, so maybe they never caught on, or maybe it's not true. Try googling.